# (Churn Rate) Count of Users in Previous Month not Present next Month for E-commerce

Tags: sql

I'm trying to Count the number of users present in previous month and weren't present in current month divided by total count of users in current month [Churn Rate]

The logic from a higher perspective would be (Count of Users in Month X - 1 not in Month X)/(Count of Users in Month X-1)

E.G.

([Count of Users in Jan]-[Count of User in Jan ∩ Feb])/ Total Count of Users in Jan)

It can't be an interval of 30 days since if a user exists in 15th of Month X-1 and appeared in 16th of Month X, then he is retained not churned.

This is a sample data

```
User_Id        Purchase_date
1               2019-01-01
5               2019-01-02
6               2019-01-02
2               2019-01-03
3               2019-01-04
1               2019-02-01
2               2019-02-04
9               2019-02-05
10              2019-02-06
11              2019-02-07
1               2019-03-04
2               2019-03-05
3               2019-03-06
4               2019-03-09
12              2019-03-09
13              2019-03-09
14              2019-03-09
15              2019-03-09
```

Feb Churn = 
[(5(count Jan)-2(count jan ∩ feb))/5(count jan)]*100
March Churn =
[(5-2)/(5)]*100

Expected Result

```
Date        Churn_Rate
January         0%
February        60%
March           60%
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Your definition of "churn rate" is also rather strange.  I would think that it would be (N-feb | N-jan) / (N-jan) (that is February users who were present in January divided by *january* users).

Comment: Yes correct, i will edit the equation, it's supposed to be divided by January Users correct @GordonLinoff thank you